# How To Send Data Using Headset Port

Tags: java, android, audio, headset

Hello I want to send data using headset port from my phone to a handmade clock as a challenge. So I Decided to use different audio frequency as different message. For example Left channel 1KHz means Hour , 1.1KHz means Minute, 1.2KHz means Day, Right channel 1KHz means 1, 1.1KHz means 2, and so on. Now I have this to make sound:

```
public class SetTimeAndDay_Activity extends Activity {
    private final int duration = 1; // seconds
    private final int sampleRate = 16000;
    private final int numSamples = duration * sampleRate;
    private final double sample[] = new double[numSamples];
    private final double freqOfTone = 1000; // hz
    private final byte generatedSnd[] = new byte[2 * numSamples];

    Handler handler = new Handler();

    int Hour, Minute, Day;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.settime_layout);

        //<editor-fold desc="Get Real Time">
        final Calendar real = Calendar.getInstance();
        Hour = real.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        Minute = real.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        Day = real.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        //</editor-fold>

        //<editor-fold desc="Preset View">
        TextView timetxt = findViewById(R.id.SetTime_Time_Txt);
        TextView datetxt = findViewById(R.id.SetTime_Day_Txt);
        ProgressBar progressBar= findViewById(R.id.SetTime_progressBar);
        timetxt.setText(Hour + ":" + Minute);
        datetxt.setText(getResources().getTextArray(R.array.WDay)[Day]);
        progressBar.setMax(100);
        progressBar.setProgress(1);
        //</editor-fold>


        // Use a new tread as this can take a while
        final Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                genTone();
                handler.post(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {
                        playSound();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        thread.start();

    }

    void genTone(){
        // fill out the array
        for (int i = 0; i < numSamples; ++i) {
            sample[i] = Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * i / (sampleRate/freqOfTone));
        }

        // convert to 16 bit pcm sound array
        // assumes the sample buffer is normalised.
        int idx = 0;
        for (final double dVal : sample) {
            // scale to maximum amplitude
            final short val = (short) ((dVal * 32767));
            // in 16 bit wav PCM, first byte is the low order byte
            generatedSnd[idx++] = (byte) (val & 0x00ff);
            generatedSnd[idx++] = (byte) ((val & 0xff00) >>> 8);

        }
    }

    void playSound(){
        final AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, numSamples,
                AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC);
        audioTrack.write(generatedSnd, 0, generatedSnd.length);
        audioTrack.play();
    }
}
```

But there is SOME PROBLEMS!

At first I can not reduce sound `duration` from a second.

Second problem is that I don't know when I could send next message. I mean how I could realize a message is sent.

Next problem is that when I define front_left channel to play, it plays from right channel too.

And last problem is that I can not realize that, headset port is connected or not.
Please Help Me Any Way And Don't Give Me Minus.

Comment: firstly, it won't be possible to differentiate  1.1KHz VS  1KHz sound with analog channel (headset port). You need larger difference. As a confirmation of *signal sent*, you can reply with some sound from your clock (*signal received* in fact)